# GroupBy a Dictionary based on key

Tags: c#, group-by

I have a `Dictionary<string,string>` that I want to group. Here are some sample key/value pairs

```
==========================
| Key            | Value |
==========================
| A_FirstValue   | 1     |
| A_SecondValue  | 2     |
| B_FirstValue   | 1     |
| B_SecondValue  | 2     |
==========================
```

Now, I want to group it according to the first letter or word in the key before the first instance of the character `'_'`

So, the final result will be `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>`. For the example above the result will be:

```
A -> A_FirstValue, 1
     A_SecondValue, 2

B -> B_FirstValue, 1
     B_SecondValue, 2
```

Is this even possible? Anyone who could help me please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Well, you could use:

```
var dictionary = dictionary.GroupBy(pair => pair.Key.Substring(0, 1))
       .ToDictionary(group => group.Key,
                     group => group.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key,
                                                 pair => pair.Value));
```

The group part will give you an `IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, and the subsequent `ToDictionary` will convert each group of key/value pairs back into a dictionary.

EDIT: Note that this will always use the first letter. For anything more complicated, I would probably write a separate `ExtractFirstWord(string)` method and call that in the `GroupBy` lambda expression.

Comment: The OP says that he wants "to group it according to the first letter or word before the first instance of the character '_'", even though his example does not support that: it's always one letter. I think `Key.Substring(0, p.Key.IndexOf('_')` would be a better choice.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `dictionary.GroupBy(g => g.Key.Substring(0, 1))`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Possibly. It's a pain when a question is ambiguously worded like this. Will edit to mention that.

Answer (score 3):

```
yourDictionary
    .GroupBy(g => g.Key.Substring(0, 1))
    .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToDictionary(k1 => k1.Key, v1 => v1.Value));
```

Comment: Note that this actually returns a `Dictionary<string, IGrouping<string, KeyValuePair<string, string>>>`.

Comment: Very helpful, I was trying to achieve a `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>` data structure as a _"ROW ID > KVP List"_ object. As @AlexanderR points out, the example creates explicit `IGrouping` reference, but can do without the `GroupBy()` clause. 

**Here's an example with System.Xml values**, if that helps anyone: 
`var lookups = dataNode.GetElementsByTagName("ROW").Cast<XmlElement>().ToDictionary(k => k.GetAttribute("id"), v => v.GetElementsByTagName("D").Cast<XmlElement>().ToDictionary(k => k.GetAttribute("n"), v => v.InnerText));`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with. Should had some error handling to ensure that an `_` exists in the Key, but should get you started.

```
        var source = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        source.Add("A_FirstValue", 1);
        source.Add("A_SecondValue", 2);
        source.Add("B_FirstValue", 1);
        source.Add("B_SecondValue", 3);

        var dest = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> entry in source) {
            string prefix = entry.Key.Split('_')[0];
            if (!dest.ContainsKey(prefix)) {
                dest.Add(prefix, new Dictionary<string, int>());
            }

            dest[prefix].Add(entry.Key, entry.Value);

        }
```